# how to disable mobile view switcher on bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, ascx

I have been designing a website with bootstrap 3 and it s responsive. I have no issue when i access the website through PC, including changing the size or the window. But when I try to check it on my mobile then the mobile.masterpage appears.

I don't want to work on mobile master page as it is already responsive.

Is there any reason why I should keep the mobile masterpage?

I would like to know how to disable the mobile view. please let me know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all go to http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints

Link.

Customize the breakpoint of the media queries as mentioned below

@screen-xs:9999px;
@screen-sm:9999px;

Now the breakpoint for the mobile devices will be 9999px and your site will be no more responsive on mobile devices.

After Updating these option just download you package by clicking the link of Compile and download button at the bottom

Comment: and can i just edit my project on visual studio on somehow? or i should download the package as you mentioned and then exchange files on the project?

Comment: You can edit it via sass or less variables , for that you need to install less or sass in your work environment . then found the variable as i mentioned above and then replace and recompile the sass or less files to bootstrap.min.css or bootstrap.css. and you are done